# ssh prompts for password despite gcr-ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to set up GNOME-Keyring such that when it is unlocked after login, it will also allow me to use my SSH key, which is encrypted.

This is a Debian 12 system. The key in question is an ed25519 SSH key, located under `.ssh/id_ed25519`.
I am using i3. The exact same setup works fine under an identical setup.

I am prompted for the keyring password after login and other services like Nextcloud only work with the correct password, so I assume that the unlock procedure works just fine.
Seahorse (the GNOME keyring GUI) lists the key, so it is known to GNOME keyring.

Status of she GCR ssh-agent wrapper:

```
systemctl status --user gcr-ssh-agent.socket
● gcr-ssh-agent.socket - GCR ssh-agent wrapper
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gcr-ssh-agent.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-03-23 16:17:15 CET; 1h 22min ago
   Triggers: ● gcr-ssh-agent.service
     Listen: /run/user/1000/gcr/ssh (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/gcr-ssh-agent.socket
```

The environment variable is set properly and the file exists:

```
> echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 
/run/user/1000/gcr/ssh

> file $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1000/gcr/ssh: socket
```

`ssh-add -l` lists the key, with the correct name and type.

And yet, when I type `ssh my-other-computer`, I am prompted for the passphrase for that key.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to debug this further!

EDIT: running ssh with `-vvv` reveals:

```
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
```

Note that this is a Debian system connecting to another Debian system (no Windows, not a PowerShell issue).

Comment: are you prompted by ssh or are you prompted by gcr?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I'm prompted by SSH. The prompt's message is the usual one without and keyring config.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that Debian 12 uses an older version of gnome-keyring, where `/run/user/1000/gcr/ssh` is **not** the socket to use.

Instead, the following old article from Arch Wiki helped me: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=GNOME/Keyring&oldid=800764#gnome-keyring-daemon_%22ssh%22_component (note the parameter `oldid` in the URL).

It describes that the socket `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` should be used. In order to make that one available, the systemd user service of `gnome-keyring-daemon.service` must be edited to have `components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh` (note the added `ssh`). I've also enabled that service in systemd: `systemctl --user enable gnome-keyring-daemon.service` and after a reboot, the file is there.

Note that this very likely applies for Debian 12 only, in my case gnome-keyring version 42.1.